# Optical mouse and x-y coordinates

Tags: c++, cursor, arduino, mouse

How do I get the x-y coordinates for an optical mouse?

I'm getting some readings while interfacing the mouse to a PC via an [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino), but it can't find a way to relate it to x-y coordinates corresponding to the mouse position.

Comment: Re *"interfacing the mouse to a PC via an Arduino"*: What kind of interfacing? What is the interface like towards to mouse? What is the interface like towards the PC? What operating system? What kind of Arduino? An [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers)? What kind of mouse? An old one with a serial interface ([COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model))?

Answer (score 0):

From the web:

> The best solution is to find a PS/2 only mouse and interface that.
>
> A USB mouse can be interfaced to Arduino using a USB Host Shield, but
> this is more expensive than the mouse (and the Arduino !), so you
> would need good reason to use it.
>
> Because the mouse works low speed USB, there is software for the AVR
> which does a bit banged low speed USB. This however is significant
> load on processor and software architecture. It would not sit so well
> with other Arduino libraries if you want a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to do more research on the operation of the [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) mouse. It does not provide x-y position data, but relative motion data, relative to the last reported motion data.

I have found two postings on GitHub with library files for interfacing a PS/2 mouse to an Arduino:

*[PS2Mouse](https://github.com/kristopher/PS2-Mouse-Arduino)*

*[arduino-ps2-mouse](https://github.com/rucek/arduino-ps2-mouse)*

Rucek provided two links to excellent articles on the operation of the PS/2 mouse:

http://computer-engineering.org/ps2mouse

http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol

These have been extremely helpful to me in understanding and implementing a PS/2 mouse on the Arduino.

Comment: The last two links are broken (the whole www.computer-engineering.org site is broken (the domain expired)). Some alternatives are (essentially the ***same content by the same author***, but slightly different titles and modification dates): *[The PS/2 Mouse/Keyboard Protocol](https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/PS2%20Keyboard.pdf)* (2003), *[The PS/2 Keyboard Interface](http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/datasheets/PS2%20Keyboard%20Protocol.htm)* (2003), and *[The AT-PS/2 Keyboard Interface](https://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Interface/atkeyboard.pdf)* (2001).

Comment: Perhaps the mouse-oriented reference is also available somewhere?